# Sticky header (position: fixed) inside an iFrame on iOS. No control over page with iFrame

Tags: ios, iphone, css, iframe, mobile

I have a sticky header (position: fixed) inside and iFrame. The header stays sticky when the page is viewed alone. Unfortunately the page gets served up in an iFrame and I have no control over the parent page.

The sticky header when viewed inside the iFrame on iOS just scrolls with the rest of the page being iFramed in.

Any way to fix this? Everything I have read says to set the height and width of the iFrame to 100% but I can't access or change the iFrame code.